# Show a different product combination data from server side on Presta 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I know that this is already available in Presta 1.6 via the hash part of a URL. However, what I need is displaying the data of the product combination on the initial page load.

I couldn't find a hook/action for when a product is found/being displayed where maybe I could just switch the default combination for the currently displayed page?

Answer (score 0):

There are several hooks on the product page that you can use:

```
displayFooterProduct
displayProductPriceBlock
displayProductTabContent
displayProductContent
displayProductTab
displayProductButtons
displayProductDeliveryTime
displayLeftColumnProduct
displayRightColumnProduct
displayProductTabContent
displayProductPriceBlock
```

Hope this helps.